# How Could I Monitor Lambda Concurrent Executions on a Second-by-Second Basis (or Find a Better Solution to Limit Lambda ConcurrentExecutions)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am working on a massive distributive computing platform built within AWS Lambda. The platform is extremely spiky, so most of the time the number of ConcurrentExecutions is below 50, but we can hit maximum (1000 currently) for up to an hour or more if a large batch job hits the system (it is an event-driven system). This is a problem as we will have customer-facing APIs that will lag terribly. Finally, I am not an architect, so I have minimal control over how the system was designed, but I have been asked to devise a clever Concurrent Execution limiting solution

I'm not new to AWS, so I know about the standard ways to handle this problem. #1 is reserve concurrency on the user-facing lambdas. I'm not allowed to do that for the sake of this exercise (though I'll go tell my boss thats whats necessary if it truly is). I'm thinking of a system where we designate high-priority (for UI) and low priority functions (for batch processing), and the low-priority functions will check a stored (DynamoDB) value output from Cloudwatch on the current number of ConcurrentExecutions. If a low priority function finds that we are in danger of using all the ConcurrentExecutions, it will post to a queue with exponential backoff in place. This all should work, save the problem that ConcurrentExecutions are only monitored in one-minute increments, which is too slow, as many of our Lambdas run for around 500ms.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Is there a way to set up a custom ConcurrentExecutions metric that has second-by-second data points, and if so, how would you do it?
2. Is there a better way to implement a counter than Cloudwatch?
3. Am I just missing something here and someone has a clever way to manage Lambda ConcurrentExecutions

Comment: Did you open a ticket to increase concurrency ? AWS is good at this kind of incremental requests for default limits.

Comment: That is a good thought, and it is something we intend to do for the production account, but our workload is spiky to the extreme, so unless we get to a number like 100000 we could still hit the limit. Concerns from up the chain about this were raised and guided me down this path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary to create a monitor or throttling solution at all. You will need to to build test and maintain something additional to your core solution. Instead, two suggestions:

Sounds like the current design has one lambda function doing too much. Decompose the Lambdas further, so you can split the Lambdas into a Ui/public lambda, and one or more dedicated to the batch processes. This way you can spread the concurrent execution limit across more Lambdas. The limit is per Lambda function.

Second, request a service quota/limit increase

> To raise the limit above 1,000 concurrent function executions, submit a request to the AWS Support Center by following the steps in our documentation. This feature is available in all regions where Lambda is available.

See AWS Lambda Raises Default Concurrent Execution Limits. 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/05/aws-lambda-raises-default-concurrent-execution-limit/

The limit management team is very flexible when asking for a limit to be raped they were generally raise it to any reasonable number that our solution requires.

To request a limit increase, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html

Comment: Would this work in production? Yes. It doesn't really answer any of my 3 questions though. For an idea of scale, within the current architecture (which the desire is to support), there would be about 20 UI/public Lambdas, and 150 batch lambdas. I could inform others this needs to change, and we could get to ~8 UI/public and 150 batch.